# C# 9 bug? CallerMemberName not working in type-omitting constructor calls

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

Suppose `TestClass` is defined like this:

```
private class TestClass
{
    public TestClass([CallerMemberName] string callerName = "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(callerName);   
    }
}
```

Then calling the constructor the old-fashioned way (`new TestClass()`) works as expected (`callerName` is automatically instantiated with the name of the calling method), but calling the constructor in the new C# 9 style doesn't seem to work:

```
TestClass _ = new(); // callerName is not instantiated and stays empty :-(
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: [Replicated](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAOgEoFcB2AXAlgWwFNkBhAe3wAdcAbQgJwGUGA3XAY0IGcBuAWABQUAEyJB4oQGYEwuABVu2QQG9BcdQgAscALIAKAJRqNqgRvNwWAQ3pwAHnAC8cTIQDu8xSRpWuXQ/xmFuoKXNjevlxwAJ5OLu4BxuoAvoKpAoJQ0iKeYRF+KkkI0qHhPn56ANokVjR09DqE+ABGDAByVkQAugiI8Oy19R1EcQBEo0ZB6qbB6kgAnHoDde2dhAY8GkXpyUA===). Looks like a bug: see if it's in https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues, and open it if not

Comment: I think it's already been reported: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/49547

Comment: Also reported: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/50475

Comment: @Izzy That's the most recent bug report, and it looks like it's being fixed.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know.

Comment: [This will be released with VS 16.9 and it's accompanying .NET SDK release (believe that will be the 5.0.200 series)](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/50475#issuecomment-765418270)